# An Experiment : A Infrared photovoltaic Cell In A Cooler Box

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, solar-cells

I like to propose an experiment here.

A Japanese research institute has developed a photovoltaic cell that can generate electricity in a total dark environment. This photovoltaic cell can generate electricity by infrared light that cannot be seen by human eyes, and light a LED lamp.

http://iftl.co.jp/news/n0029/news0029.html  . It's in Japanese, you can translate to English by Google translate.

So, I'm thinking an experiment:  a infrared photovoltaic cell is placed in a cooler box  and the wires connecting the positive and negative poles of the infrared photovoltaic cell  connect to a light  outside the cooler box. Then the light should work and consume energy.  Does  the temperature in the cooler box drop?

If the temperature does not decrease, there are two reasons: 1 The infrared battery does not work, 2  the law of conservation of energy has  problems. But as long as the light is on, it means that the infrared photovoltaic cell works. Obviously, the law of conservation of energy is unquestionable.

If the temperature  decrease, the energy is transferred to the outside of cooler box. That means  the second law of thermodynamics has problems and needs to be revised. The second kind of perpetual motion machine may work.

Answer (score 1):

Photovoltaics function as optical heat engines. Their efficiency is limited by the Carnot efficiency. The photovoltaic in the box will only produce electricity while it is colder than the incoming infra-red radiation source (the rest of the box).

During that time it will indeed be able to light the lamp and reduce the overall thermal energy in the box. Once it reaches the same temperature as the rest of the box there will be no more electrical power produced.

Both the conservation of energy and the 2nd law of thermodynamics are respected with photovoltaics.

Comment: The Kelvin–Planck statement (or the heat engine statement) of the second law of thermodynamics states that:

It is impossible to devise a cyclically operating device, the sole effect of which is to absorb energy in the form of heat from a single thermal reservoir and to deliver an equivalent amount of work. 

But the energy come from a single thermal reservoir in this experiment. This against the Kelvin–Planck statement (or the heat engine statement) of the second law of thermodynamics states.

Comment: No, that is not how photovoltaics work. There are always two reservoirs. One is the temperature of the source of the incoming radiation and the other is the temperature of the photovoltaic cell itself. You cannot have a photovoltaic without those two reservoirs and the photovoltaic is limited by the Carnot efficiency between them, going to zero as the temperatures equalize.

Comment: You mean that why photovoltatics works is because the two reservoirs has temperature difference. We can wait until they both at same temperature before connect to the LED light

Comment: Then there will be no current produced and the light will not turn on.

Comment: you should read this :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photovoltaic_effect nothing about temperature

Comment: And you should read more than just Wikipedia: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-009-3817-5_202 just because one specific Wiki article fails to mention something doesn’t mean it isn’t important

Comment: Can anyone do this experiment? Physics is based on experiment.